# Newest questions start 4 hours ago

Tags: bug

I have this weird bug: When I clicked newest questions it starts with questions that were posted four hours ago. Two hours ago, I had the same problem, although then it started with questions that were posted two hours ago, and it took about a quarter before it was fixed. I tried the following things:

- Reloading page of course
- Logging out and in
- Restart browser

Is this a way to fix this? (It is fixed now, but I don't want to run in the same bug again)

Comment: This happens from time to time, see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9479/43351) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6152/43351). Usually it resolves itself after a short period of time.

Comment: [This](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) is the standard reply in this situation.